# Quoted font 'sans-serif' not working properly in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I’m writing a small static site (HTML and CSS) and stumbled about a behavior in the property `font-family`, which I don’t understand. I like to write my code consistent with a nice and clean look, that’s why always quote fonts in CSS.

As far as I understand the [CSS2.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) correct, quoted fonts are allowed:

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted
>   as a sequence of one or more identifiers.

Unfortunately, it’s not working properly in my case. I attached an example below.

```css
.test1
{
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
}

.test2
{
    font-family: 'arial';
}

.test3
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test1">Test</h1>
<h1 class="test2">Test</h1>
<h1 class="test3">Test</h1>
```

I tested the property with Google Chrome 54.0.2840.99 and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18450. Why is the quoted font for `arial` working but not for `sans-serif`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sans-serif is not the name of the font but the font type...
In order to make a font work, you have to type at least the font name!
Font name in required.
Ex

```
.myclass{font-family: 'myFontName', sans-serif;}
```

> - family-name - The name of a font-family, like "times", "courier",    "arial", etc.
> - generic-family - The name of a generic-family, like "serif",    "sans-serif", "cursive", "fantasy", "monospace".

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)